# authz directory identifiers not support

Tags: svn, authz

Without using the authz, all the svn users can login and use the repos without issues.
However, I would like to limit the access to some directories - not to be readable or writeable for all users.

`svnserve --version` => `1.6.6`

I tried both, granting access to users and groups. I also tried it separate, only group or only user access.

```
[groups]
admingroup=i_can_access_anything
limitedgroup=i_am_limited
[/]
#*=
@admingroup=rw
i_can_access_anything=rw
[projectX]
#i also tried [repository:/projectX]
#*=
@limitedgroup=rw
i_am_limited=rw
```

Trying to access the / or /projectX at the svn fails. => access denied
Without the authz, it works properly, but also grants access to other projects that do not belong to the "limited" user group :-/

Do you see what's wrong there?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is some problem with the way you are trying to give access.

Instead try using this:-

a. Say if your user who is login in svn using id as "admin" whom you want to give all the rights (read/write) and say there is another user who is login using id as "normal" who is having rights (read only) to some specific folder (projectX) only then

```
[groups]
admingroup=admin
limitedgroup=normal

[/]    
*=

[repository:/projectX]
@admingroup=rw
@limitedgroup=r
```

Basically here you are giving the read and write access on projectX folder to admingroup and giving only read access on projectX folder to limitedgroup.

b. If this is not working then please try using "VisualSVN Server". It has a very nice gui to add users and give them priviledges also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: edited again and again.. now it seems to run, without "repository:", only /directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should start every directory section with a leading "**/**":

```
  [/projectX]
```

[More info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)